# why I get error when call [myclass alloc] misx c++ to object-c++ to object-c?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

i try use call c++ from object c
use B4I
this code but i get error
i already use file.mm

### this file Greeting.cpp

```
#include "Greeting.hpp"

Greeting::Greeting() {
    greeting = "Hello C++!";
}

std::string Greeting::greet() {
    return greeting;
}
```

---

this file Greeting.hpp

---

```
    #ifndef Greeting_hpp
#define Greeting_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class Greeting {
    std::string greeting;
public:
    Greeting();
    std::string greet();
};
#endif /* Greeting_hpp */
```

---

this file ViewController.h

---

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (void)showGreeting;

@end
```

---

this file ViewController.mm

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Greeting.hpp"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    Greeting greeting;
    IBOutlet UIButton *helloButton;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)showGreeting {

 NSLog(@"test %@");

}


@end
```

---

i try call it

---

```
 ViewController* ViewController1= [[ViewController alloc] init];
  [ ViewController1 showGreeting ];
```

---

i get error unknown method

```
-------------------------------
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in b4i_main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
---------------------------------
```

when i use

```
ViewController* ViewController1;
  [ ViewController1 showGreeting ];
```

return null
note  this example HelloCpp-master

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to call a c++ class from an objc app using a method in AppDelegate.  It may be run in Terminal by first saving the source code in a file named 'greet.mm' and then using this command: clang greet.mm -framework Cocoa -o greet && ./greet

```
//clang greet.mm -framework Cocoa -o greet && ./greet

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

class Greeting {
public:
  void greet();
};

void Greeting::greet() {
  NSLog(@"Hello C++!");
}

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
  NSWindow *window;
}
- (void) myBtnAction: (id)sender;
- (void) buildMenu;
- (void) buildWnd;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) myBtnAction: (id)sender {
  Greeting g;
  g.greet();
}

- (void) buildMenu {
 NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
 NSMenuItem *menuBarItem = [NSMenuItem new];
 [menubar addItem:menuBarItem];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
 NSMenuItem *quitMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit"
 action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
 [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
 [menuBarItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
}

- (void) buildWnd {    
#define _wndW  200
#define _wndH  150
 window = [ [ NSWindow alloc ] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )
    styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskTitled
    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
 [window center];
 [window setTitle: @"Test window" ];
 [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    
// **** My Button **** //
 NSButton *myBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 40, 80, 125, 24 )];
 [myBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
 [myBtn setTitle: @"Run CPP Class"];
 [myBtn setAction: @selector (myBtnAction:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: myBtn];

// **** Quit btn **** //
 NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 )];
 [quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
 [quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
 [quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
[self buildMenu];
[self buildWnd];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

@end

int main () {
 NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
 [app setDelegate:appDelegate];
 [NSApp run];
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but i get error `/Users/administrator/Documents/UploadedProjects/<user id>/B4iProject/main.m:13:2: error: unknown type name 'clang'
 clang greet.mm -framework Cocoa -o greet && ./greet
 ^
/Users/administrator/Documents/UploadedProjects/<user id>/B4iProject/main.m:13:13: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
 clang greet.mm -framework Cocoa -o greet && ./greet
            ^
            ;
2 errors generated.`

Comment: and this error  ` #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> ` get error ` fatal error: 'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.`

Comment: Note: I use iPhone so can't ` import cocoa.h `

Comment: Do you have CommandLineTools installed?  Should also be able to run in Xcode by using objective-c project (don't delete AppDelegate provided).  Rename 'main.m' to 'main.mm' and copy/paste above code into it.  Don't worry about having two AppDelegates, because you need the original for this to work.

Comment: thank you .. I not have her CommandLineTools installed so this where I add (clang greet.mm -framework Cocoa -o greet && ./greet) ?
..so

Comment: Do you have Terminal available (looks like a black tv set).  Type clang -v on the command line and it will show if you have it installed.

Comment: ` NSApplication  ` cant use with ios.. can use UIApplication.. or I wrong?

Comment: example B4I install with hosted bulider ..thank you for you answer..and I am sorry distrub

Answer (score 0):

Should run in iOS.  Change extension of ViewController from .m to .mm

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end

#import "ViewController.h"

class Greeting {
public:
  void greet();
};

void Greeting::greet() {
  NSLog(@"Hello C++!");
}

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *LaunchBtn;

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)showGreeting:(id)sender {
  Greeting g;
  g.greet();
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer .. you right ..but please you can write how file ` ViewController.h ` ?

Comment: I alreay Change extension of ViewController from .m to .mm..nothing ..not work

Comment: I'm sorry that you are having trouble.  It works fine either in Xcode or when run in Terminal.